# Copy some values between List<> and List2<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, ienumerable

i have 2 LIST

```
List<PrimeraVueltaFindResult> ListaPrimeraVuelta = new List<PrimeraVueltaFindResult>();
List<RutaCriticaFindResult> result = new List<RutaCriticaFindResult>();

public class PrimeraVueltaFindResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string JobNameInicio { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string GroupInicio { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StartRun { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string JobNameFin { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string GroupFin { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EndRun { get; set; }
}

public class RutaCriticaFindResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public int RutaCriticaId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StartRun { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EndRun { get; set; }

}
```

I need to copy StartRun and EndRun in PrimeraVueltaFindResult List Values.

Please how can i do this???

Comment: According to what logic? I don't see any obvious relation between your 2 classes....

Comment: Well, they both have `StartRun` and `EndRun` properties.

Answer (score 4):

To copy all of the data out of `ListaPrimeraVuelta` into new `RutaCriticaFindResult` objects you can use LINQ:

```
var rutaCriticaFindResults = ListaPrimeraVuelta.Select(result => 
    new RutaCriticaFindResult 
    { 
        StartRun = result.StartRun, 
        EndRun = result.EndRun 
    });

var result = rutaCriticaFindResults.ToList();
```